# Create Customized Functionality in SSRS:s Report Server?

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, mdx

Goal:
Create an additional functionality in report server. It is a button or an address link and when you press it then you open a Excel application containing a customized templete. The Excel's sheet is connected to a cube in SSAS.

Problem:
Is it possible to do it to fullfill the goal?

Information:
*The report server is located in a server and the user use client computer. If endusers gonna review the report in report server, they have to type the IP number and "reportserver" in the webrowser's address field.
*Using SSAS as a datasource.
*You should enable to save the document in the end user's computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload non-SSRS files to the SSRS report server with Upload File button.  [image: View of upload wizard]

This means you can upload a template workbook configured however you'd like it.  So long as the user does not have the ability to publish to SSRS then the only locations they'd be able to save it are the locations they could save any file on the network.